# C++11 Thread Exception Propogation in Visual Studio (Express 2013)

Tags: c++11

My question is: Is the following observed behavior consistent with the C++11 spec or is it a Microsoft extension to the language?

In a test program (using Visual Studio Express 2013) I am testing out exception propagation from a function run in thread -- to the parent thread. Without using the prescribed exception pointer stuff it all works OK... and this had me wondering if this is actually a Microsoft Extension to the language going on.

So I set "Disable Language Extensions" and now not even Hello World compiles (C2400: inline assembler syntax error) so I am no closer to knowing if the observed behavior is consistent with the standard.

Reading some other questions here gives me the impression that the following should not work.

```
int myFunc() { throw <various types tried here>; }

int main() {
    auto fut = std::async(myFunc);
    //...

    try {
        int retVal = fut.get();
    }
    catch(<corresponding type here>) {

        // matching exception is always caught here in parent 

    }
}
```

Comment: For completeness sake only -- as stated in the question above Visual Studio has these "inline assembler" errors when language extensions are disabled. As I reduced my Hello World program even more I found that the problem goes away when I don't include <future>.  Some checking in the MS forums led to a post answer claiming this happens when certain template syntax is used. Maybe that syntax is used in the <future> header. That compiler problem was noted in a post that was answered in 2007.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From §30.6.6/17 of the standard, `std::future::get()`

> *Throws*: the stored exception, if an exception was stored in the shared state.

And from §30.6.8/3 of the standard, when using `std::async()` with policy `std::launch::async`,

> Any exception propagated from the execution of `INVOKE(DECAY_COPY(std::forward<F>(f)), DECAY_COPY(std::forward<Args>(args))...)` is stored as the exceptional result in the shared state.

With policy `std::launch::deferred`, there is no special behavior required for the exception to propagate up as observed.

So yes, this behavior is consistent with the C++11 spec.